# text/x-magento-init not getting triggered at all

Tags: magento2, requirejs

Can't get `text/x-magento-init` to get triggered, I'm simply trying to inject trivial custom JavaScript.

In my `phtml` template

```html
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "x/js/y/z": {}
    }
}
</script>
```

does nothing, it's never executed. Tried a more specific selector, tried `data-mage-init`, same result.

```html
<script>
    requirejs(['x/js/y/z'], function () {
    })
</script>
```

works.

`x/js/y/z.js` content

```js
define([], function () {
    alert("x");
    return {};
});
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: hi @Ravenous did you get any solution for this problem i facing same problem.